# Rx how to take first n elements of a sequence within time interval and ignore others

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm using Rx in my programm and want to create subscription for observable that takes 5 first elements within one minute time interval and ignores others.
For example,

```
Sequence: -1---2--3--4-5---6---7-8--------------
Interval: |------------------|------------------|
Result:   |1---2--3--4-5-----|-7-8--------------|
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Window` + `SelectMany` + `Take` would work in this case:

```
var subscription = source.Window(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
      .SelectMany(w => w.Take(5))
      .Subscribe(item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

Comment: Works like a treat. I created a test sequence using the `TestScheduler` and it performed exactly as required.